# Is there any inbuilt way in JS to check if any of the elements of a form has a customValidity equals non empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am open to using jQuery. I thought of this method below using jquery:

```
$('#form-id').find(':invalid').length === 0
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do it.
I am thinking if I can check custom validity of an input element to determine whether the element has valid data or not then there might be a method to check custom validity of its parent form which will return false if any of its child elements has non empty custom validity set.

I don't want to loop over each of the elements of form to check their custom validity rather I want to check the validity of form as a whole. "Validity of form as a whole" means if all the elements of form are containing valid inputs (that is, none of their custom validity is set to non empty string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input:invalid` or `.checkValidity()` to validate the html5 fields.

```js
$("#check").click(function(){
  var invalidCount = $("#form input:invalid").length;
  if(invalidCount === 0)
    alert("valid");
  else 
    alert("invalid");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="a" required>
  <input type="text" name="a" required>
</form>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```